# How to set cursor in the input field once i clear data-reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to clear the input field and make the cursor to focus on the same input field. I tried using `.focus()` and autofocus function, but still I am not able to get the values.

```
resetInput = () => {
  this.setState({ search: '' });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="storyboard-search-box clearfix">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." value={this.state.search} onChange={this.searchBoard} />
      <button className="clear-search-button">
        <img src={clearIcon} alt="clear button" title="Clear All" onClick={this.resetInput}/>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`ref` callback in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

```
resetInput = () => {
  this.setState({ search: '' });
  if (this.textInput) this.textInput.focus();
}

<div className="storyboard-search-box clearfix">
  <input ref={ref => { this.textInput = ref }} type="text" placeholder="Search..." value={this.state.search} onChange={this.searchBoard} />
  <button className="clear-search-button">
    <img src={clearIcon} alt="clear button" title="Clear All" onClick={this.resetInput}/>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `ref` of the `input`, and call the `focus` method on that.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  searchBoard = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };

  resetInput = () => {
    this.setState({ search: "" });
    this.ref.focus();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.resetInput, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={this.state.search}
          onChange={this.searchBoard}
          ref={ref => (this.ref = ref)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```